# Android Navigation Component load 2 nested Fragments into Parent Fragment

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation

I have a Comparator Screen which is a Fragment that is splitted into 2 sub-screens. Before using Navigation Component I could easily just:

```
 private void initializeFragments() {

        FoodComparatorFragment comparatorFragment1 = new FoodComparatorFragment();
        FoodComparatorFragment comparatorFragment2 = new FoodComparatorFragment();

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.comparator_fragment_1, comparatorFragment1);
        transaction.add(R.id.comparator_fragment_2, comparatorFragment2);

        transaction.commit();
    }
```

However, I don't know how I should perform this operation with the Navigation Component WITHOUT using explicitly the `FragmentManager`.

Comment: So your Comparator Screen is a fragment that is made up of two child fragments? What makes you think you can't still do that?

Comment: Yes, but the purpose of Navigation Components in theory is to remove the need of using FragmentManager. I was wondering if there is a way to do this without using FragmentManager

Comment: As the creator of the Navigation Component, that's not quite right - it was to remove the need to write FragmentTransactions to manage a back stack. You don't need to write FragmentTransactions or manage a back stack for two static fragments - why not [add them in XML](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/create#add-xml)?

Comment: What if I need to pass some arguments or bundle to the above mentioned fragments? Can this be done using XML or in this specific scenario am I forced to use manually FragmentManager instead of Navigation Component ? @ianhanniballake

Comment: Hey @NexussimLements Are you familiar with Kotlin to post it as answer, if not I'd convert it to java

Comment: I can understand Kotlin without problems @Zain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default with navigation components there is one `NavHostFragment` hosted by the main activity for one activity/many fragments model. For many activities/fragments model, each activity has its own `NavHostFragment/NavGraph`.

Here we'll consider one activity, many fragments model, where one of these fragments is the Comparator Screen (parent fragment) that is splitted into 2 sub-screens/fragments.

But the `NavHostFragment` can only host a single fragment at a time; so the idea here is to have two `NavHostFragments` within the comparator/parent fragment.

---

### Considering the below example:

- We have a `MainActivity` that hosts two fragments (`HomeFragment`, `ParentFragment`).
- The `ParentFragment` is the comparator with two `NavHostFragments`, each can host a single fragment; the top one is `TopFragment`, the bottom is `BottomFragment`.
- There is an action to go from the `HomeFragment` to the `ParentFragment`
- There is `int` argument sent to each sub-screen, the Top/Bottom fragments, done by sending arguments to the sub-screens along with the action from the `HomeFragment` to the `ParentFragment`; they will be displayed on `TextViews` on the screen.

```
MainActivity (1 NavHostFragments/NavGraph) ->> nav_host_fragment_activity_main
    |
    |---- HomeFragment
    |
    |---- ParentFragment (2 NavHostFragments/NavGraphs) ->> top_nav_host_fragment & bottom_nav_host_fragment
    |       |
    |       |---- TopFragment
    |       |
    |       |---- BottomFragment
```

#### **Now we have 3 NavGraphs:**

Main (mobile_navigation.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/navigation_home">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:name="com.example....HomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_homeFragment_to_parentFragment"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_parent"
            app:popUpTo="@id/navigation_home"
            app:popUpToInclusive="false" />

    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_parent"
        android:name="com.example....ParentFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_parent"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_parent">

        <argument
            android:name="top_arg"
            android:defaultValue="-1"
            app:argType="integer" />

        <argument
            android:name="bottom_arg"
            android:defaultValue="-1"
            app:argType="integer" />

    </fragment>

</navigation>
```

[image]

**And in `ParentFragment`, another two `NavGraphs`, each for a sub-screen:**

For the 1st sub-screen (top_navigation.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/top_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/top_fragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/top_fragment"
        android:name="com.example.....TopFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_top">

        <argument
            android:name="arg"
            android:defaultValue="-1"
            app:argType="integer" />

    </fragment>

</navigation>
```

For the 2nd sub-screen (bottom_navigation.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/bottom_fragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/bottom_fragment"
        android:name="com.example.....BottomFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_bottom">

        <argument
            android:name="arg"
            android:defaultValue="-1"
            app:argType="integer" />

    </fragment>

</navigation>
```

**Layouts:**

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_activity_main"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

fragment_parent.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.fragments.HomeFragment">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/top_nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/teal_200"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_nav_host_fragment"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/purple_200"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/top_nav_host_fragment" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

fragment_top/bottom.xml are straightforward

fragment_top.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.fragments.ParentFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:text="top fragment"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The `NavGraph` of the Top & Bottom fragments will be set programmatically in order to allow passing the arguments from the main `NavGraph` to the sub-screens' `NavGraphs`.

Now in the `HomeFragment`, there is a button to go to the `ParentFragment` with the action defined in the `NavGraph`, which sends the arguments needed for both sub-screens:

```
findNavController().navigate(
    HomeFragmentDirections.actionHomeFragmentToParentFragment()
    .setTopArg(100)
    .setBottomArg(200))
```

Then receive the arguments at the `ParentFragment` with the `SafeArgs`:

```
// get fragment arguments through SafeArgs
val args = ParentFragmentArgs.fromBundle(requireArguments()) 
val bottomBundle = Bundle()
bottomBundle.putInt("arg", args.bottomArg)
val topBundle = Bundle()
topBundle.putInt("arg", args.topArg)
// setting the navGraph of the top/bottom NavHostFragments, 
// and pass the argument along as a bundle.
val bottomNavHostFragment =
    childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.bottom_nav_host_fragment)
            as NavHostFragment
bottomNavHostFragment.navController.setGraph(R.navigation.bottom_navigation, bottomBundle)

val topNavHostFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.top_nav_host_fragment)
        as NavHostFragment
topNavHostFragment.navController.setGraph(R.navigation.top_navigation, topBundle)
```

Once more at the destination top/bottom sub-screens, get the argument with `safeArgs`, and set it to the `TextView`:

```
// TopFragment
textView.text = TopFragmentArgs.fromBundle(
    requireArguments()
).arg.toString()

// BottomFragment
textView.text = BottomFragmentArgs.fromBundle(
    requireArguments()
).arg.toString()
```

[image]